# Could not load type System.Net.HttpStatusCode' from assembly 'System.Net" in Google Cloud Storage Client library for .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-client

I Have referenced Google Cloud Storage client library in my project by installing it with Package Manager Console in visual studio 2010.I am getting following error while downloading file.

[image]

.Net Framework 4.0 is installed on web server. I have tried following thing to resolve the same but no success

1. Added  in web.config and then run the site but still error persist
2. set system.net dll to copy to local and added in bin folder of site and then run the site but still error persist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wasting Half day finally i got solution to the problem, Just installed the [Patch](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3556) for .NET Framework 4.0 and done!!!

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5927